# Is it possible to initialize use the reactive declaration of Sveltejs with array element?

Tags: svelte

I have an array of units:

```js
let units = ['mm', 'cm', 'm', 'km', 'in', 'yd', 'ft-us', 'ft', 'mi'];
```

And I want to make a reactive property that changes when the array changes. Something like this:

```js
$: unit = units[0]

function changeUnits(){
    units = ['rad', 'deg', 'grad'];
}
```

The idea here is to retrieve the first value of the `units` array every time it changes. So the initial value of `unit` is `mm` and after the `changeUnits()` function the is called the new value should be `rad` but instead the value of `unit` unit is `undefined`.

I'm new to svelte with a reactjs background so I'm unable to wrap my head around this concept. Any help would be appreciated and thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for the most part but there is a pitfall here in the execution order of reactive statements: They only update with the component update cycle.

I.e. the variable will be `undefined` until the first update runs ([demonstration](https://svelte.dev/repl/9a87845220c040158bfd23a687a72122?version=4.2.8)).

With this source code:

```js
let units = ['mm', 'cm', 'm', 'km', 'in', 'yd', 'ft-us', 'ft', 'mi'];
$: unit = units[0]

function changeUnits(){
    units = ['rad', 'deg', 'grad'];
}
```

You get this output:

```js
let unit; // <- undefined at first
let units = ['mm', 'cm', 'm', 'km', 'in', 'yd', 'ft-us', 'ft', 'mi'];

function changeUnits() {
    $$invalidate(2, units = ['rad', 'deg', 'grad']);
}

$$self.$$.update = () => {
    if ($$self.$$.dirty & /*units*/ 4) {
        $: $$invalidate(0, unit = units[0]); // <- assignment happens here
    }
};
```

So if you want to use the `unit` in the script right away, you may have to work around this by e.g. doing something like this:

```js
let unit = units[0];
$: unit = units[0];
```

(These workarounds will not be necessary in Svelte 5.)

Comment: Thanks brunnerh. I don't really understand it but it works perfectly. Yes I heard that Svelte 5 will introduce Runes